# Selenium Chord Method

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to try and send a shift+tab in selenium c#. I did some research and I kept seeing a keys.chord method but I do not see that method. I am using current selenium webdriver 2.47. I have tried the below but it is throwing an error on the keys.tab call - key must be a modifier key (Keys.Shift, Keys.Control, or Keys.Alt)

```
    public static void KeyComboTabBack()
    {

        Actions actions  = new Actions(SeleniumDriver);
        actions.KeyDown(Keys.Shift);
        actions.KeyDown(Keys.Tab);
        actions.Perform();

    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to send both in the same action:

```
driver.FindElement(ByLocator).SendKeys(Keys.Shift + Keys.Tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use robot class

```
 Robot r = new Robot(); 
  r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
```

Comment: isn't the `Robot` class purely a Java related library (used with HAL)??